# Youtube API isssue

Tags: flutter, api, http-status-code-404

I'm a new flutter learner,
Getting an error 404 while connecting Youtube API with the flutter app

here is my api call

```
@override


Future<Either<MainFailures, VideoListModel>> getVideoListWithDio() async {
VideoListModel list;
Map<String, dynamic> queryParameters = {
  "part": "snippet",
  "chart": "mostPopular",
  "maxResults": 25,
  "regionCode": "IN",
  'key': API_KEY,
};
// option = Options(headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
try {
  final data = await Dio()
      .get(APIEndPoints.videoListUrl, queryParameters: queryParameters);
  list = VideoListModel.fromJson(data.data);
  print(list.pageInfo);

  return Right(list);
} catch (exception) {
  print(exception);
  return const Left(MainFailures.clientFailure());
}


}
```

here is the error

```
DioError [DioErrorType.response]: Http status error [404]
```

Please suggest to me a solution to it.

Comment: What is your url? Seems to point to something that is not found.

Comment: What's the value of `APIEndPoints.videoListUrl`??

Comment: https://youtube.googleapis.com/yotube/v3/videos

Comment: i tried  www.googleapis.com with this one also, that time i get an error  


DioError [DioErrorType.other]: Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI www.googleapis.com/yotube/v3/videos?part=snippet&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=25&regionCode=IN&key=AIzaSyBYwPBTu5GhY2nPsF78MWtzN6rLAp-qjr8

Comment: Note that you have typed `yotube` instead of `youtube` and you also shared your private API key... Please destroy it and use a new one.

Comment: Does it solve your original problem ?

Comment: Yes, it was the spell mistake